# SslStream with a TcpListener: Can't Authenticate As Server

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

**EDIT:** GitHub path to example project is here: https://oobi.visualstudio.com/_git/HttpHost

please excuse my noobish-ness with SSL and secure streams. I've done research to try and get past it on my own, but haven't seen a case like this.

I'm trying to create a portable HTTPS server module (Called HttpHost, because it will also support HTTP once the hard stuff is out of the way) for use in other programs I may have in mind down the road, but for the life of me I cannot get the server to accept connections even though the clients show no issues shaking hands.

My code is rather simple to initialize and start it:

```
X509Certificate2 inputCert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\matt\\Matthew.pfx"); //self signed cert
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(inputCert);
host.StartSecureListen();
```

HttpHost when initialized does this:

```
public HttpHost(X509Certificate cert, int HTTPSport = DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT) {
    // variable validation and some other unrelated junk here...

    this._listener = new TcpListener(_localIP, _port);
}
```

The HttpHost class creates a new thread with a *ParameterizedThreadStart* for each incoming request, and processes them through this void:

```
private void ProcessSecureRequest(object arg) {
    TcpClient client = arg as TcpClient;
    string outputHTTPstatus = HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString();
    string outputMimeType = "text/xml";

    Console.WriteLine("InboundConnection: Client(" + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.AddressFamily.ToString() + ")");

    Console.WriteLine("DATA: " + ReadMessageFromSecureClient(client));

    client.Close();
}
```

### This is where things get interesting

I have a void responsible for taking the TCP client, and reading the data being sent:

```
private string ReadMessageFromSecureClient(TcpClient client) {
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(_serverCert, false, SslProtocols.Tls, false); // <--- ERROR HERE


    byte[] byteBuff = new byte[];
    StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
    int bytes = -1;

    do {
        bytes = sslStream.Read(byteBuff , 0, byteBuff.Length);
        Decoder dec = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        char[] chars = new char[dec .GetCharCount(byteBuff, 0, bytes) - 1 + 1];
        dec .GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
        messageData.Append(chars);        
    }
    while (bytes != 0);

    return messageData.ToString();
}
```

When navigating to 'https://localhost' from a browser (Edge Dev based off of Chromium) while the program is debugging, an exception is **always** thrown when attmepting to AuthenticateAsServer. The debugger says:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'
Inner: Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
```

And when using Insomnia (REST/HTTP API Tester) and sending a blank GET request to the server, I get this error:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'
Inner: Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
```

I've already installed this certificate into the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' folder of the local machine.
But, when using OpenSSL to verify the SSL handshake between the client and server (run on a different machine than the debugger), it completes with no errors:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.100:443 -tls1_2
```

```
CONNECTED(0000011C)
───
no peer certificate available
───
No client certificate CA names sent
───
SSL handshake has read 1399 bytes and written 201 bytes
Verification: OK
───
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1583735493
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
───
```

I created this certificate with the powershell "New-SelfSignedCertificate", and I can't seem to find a way to successfully authenticate a SSL connection. I'm sorry this is so long, I wanted to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: first check in a brower advance settings if TLS 1.2 is enabled.  There arre many different encryption modes and setting sfor TLS/SSL and the default settings in Net library is different that the certificate you are using.  You code is calling new X509Certificate2 which is doing the certificate validation.  Many people who had working code started to get issues when Microsoft updated Net to 4.7.  I believe the issue was Net 4.7 defaulted to 64 bit encryption.  I have not seen any responses how to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your input!! I know the browser has TLS 1.2 enabled, because when I use any other encryption method (SSL3, TLS 1 or 1.1), I receive an "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" message from my browser. I am sure that TLS 1.2 is supported by Edge Dev (Chromium). I also discovered, if i add a try/catch statement to keep the application going, and repeatedly send requests from the browser, I can eventually see the plaintext HTTP request...?

Comment: It may be looking for a proxy and the default timeout is 30 seconds.  There may not be a proxy, so you may be seeing 30 seconds before getting a good response while waiting for the proxy timeout.  You can turn off the proxy.

Comment: I cannot figure this out, so i'll be switching to an HttpListener, using HttpListenerContext, HttpListenerRequest, and HttpListenerResponse is much easier to handle this. I would have loved to control the SSL communication down to the byte level, and be able to construct my own HTTP responses by hand, but it seems as though it won't be possible, for now :(

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication

Comment: This was VERY useful, thank you. It seems as though HttpListener and related object do the handshake technique for you, but I thought that a TcpListener running AuthenticateAsServer with the incoming stream (as an SslStream) would *also* preform this handshake. I'm lost, but I've managed to fit all use cases into an HttpListener for now. Will certainly implement a TcpListener if anyone can figure out what's happening here.

Comment: There was a posting a couple of weeks ago where an OP OR'd both TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in the request.  Then sent a request with TLS1.2 and server came back with response TLS1.1  The authentication was never done with TLS1.1 the server only acknowledged it supported TLS1.1 (not 1.2).  When a client connects to a server a negotiation occurs to determine a common mode to use for connections using the headers in the request and the headers in the server.  With TLS the authentication is not automatic and must be initiated.

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I solved this.

Everytime you refer to System.Net.Security.SslStream make sure SslProtocol is forced to System.Security.Authentication.Tls12 not just Tls nor Tls11

A simple fix that did it for me.
My js client was getting, as you stated above :
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

My C# service was getting:
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The function requested is not supported

Answer (score 0):

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false,
                enabledSslProtocols:
                    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls |
                    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 |
                    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 |
                    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3
                , checkCertificateRevocation: true);
```

Comment: A code blob without explanation is not a good answer. Also, this answer does not solve the problem the OP ran into.